# Apache Configuration for A Container+Subdomain's SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, docker

In January I configured and installed SSL certificates for two subdomains. After that, I then connected two docker containers to those subdomains.

That configuration's SSL was "working" until the SSL renewal process began. The certifier then tried to update the keys in the /.well-known/ directory, but due to the container now being installed it was trying to look inside the container for the /.well-known/ directory.

Is there a Docker command or Apache configuration to make the SSL certbot look to the /.well-known/ directory on the main server and not try and find it inside the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by disconnecting the containers, I then manually installed a 1 year certificate. Then I reconnected the containers.

A CPanel limitation, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache as a reverse proxy on your host you can redirect requests to the /.well-known/ directory using a directory block:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/.well-known/">
    Require all granted
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</ Directory>
```

Your acme-client should then place  the challenges in /var/www/html/.well-known/ on your host machine. [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/all-instructions) can do this automatically, check your host operating system manual on the linked page.

Alternatively if you are open to change to NGINX, I can recommend using docker [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) with it's [acme-companion](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/) for Let's Encrypt/ZeroSSL. This combination automatically issues certificates/renewals for your docker-containers.

Comment: ```WARN Local HTTP DCV error (sub.domain.tld): The system queried for a temporary file at “http://sub.domain.tld/.well-known/pki-validation/_ID_.txt”, but the web server responded with the following error: 404 (Not Found). A DNS (Domain Name System) or web server misconfiguration may exist.```

The solution seems right. I'll have to toy with the config a bit. cPanel is so limiting.